# GUI library using SVG as renderer?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, svg

I recently had to implement a few widgets such as Button,Checkbox,Toggle-Button with SVG (Dojo-based) and I am facing now more widgets : combo-box, lists and a few more. I am pretty impressed by the results, especially about the precision of the widgets, working in all browsers. Thats a huge difference to me compared with classical GUI implementations done with jQuery and friends...

At that time there wasn't anything around and I'm very curious why nobody touched the topic yet. Is it just the wrong way to use SVG as renderer or is it just to early ?

However, I am of course interested to benefit or contribute from/to existing projects but are there any in progress ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you get very far with your SVG home-grown components?

Comment: hi, it was all ok, that project however was quite long ago and we changed to HTML. i remember to performance trouble when it came to more complex code along the renderer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally someone did the right step : http://www.dotuscomus.com/pergola/index.html